# Loop behavior in python

Tags: python, loops, operators, increment, cpython

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 2:
        i += 2
    print(i,end=",")
```

I want to print 0,1,4,5,6,7,8,9
but it is printing 0,1,4,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.
Is there any way to fix this??

Comment: Lookup [continue](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while-loop:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    if i == 2:
        i += 2
    print(i, end=",")
    i += 1
```

The for for-loop will rebind the loop variable in each iteration. The while-loop gives you more control.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
for i in range(8):
  if i >= 2 :
    i += 2
  print(i,end=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the overall logic, this might also do the trick.

```py
for i in range(10):
    if i not in [2, 3]:
        print(i,end=",")
```